# Size of a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any lmitation on the size of a bash script? If yes, is there any effect of sourced scripts on the size?

Comment: The short answer is no. The long answer is that you're unlikely to write a script where you could measure the marginal effect of making the script longer. Eventually, of course, you'll run out of disk space .

Comment: What's the problem do you want to solve? I think, it's a design error if you want to write such a large script. Let's see the original problem, and solve that.

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/DEVOPS_BORAT/status/148473290137157632

Comment: Sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I have a number of shell scipts, each 500~1000 lines, containing many functions. I `source` all of them in one main script, where I implement the main workflow. Since `sourcing` is like including those scripts inside the main script, the accumulated size is becoming beyond 10K lines. Is it a bad design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your script starts encroaching on 10K lines, it is (long past) time that you thought about writing some smaller scripts for it to use.  However, the shell won't blink at a script that big.

So, the limit is on the comprehensibility of the script - if it gets too big, it gets unmaintainable.  Pragmatically, there is no other limit on the size of the script; there is certainly no formal upper bound (so there's no magic number N where at N-1 bytes you are OK and at N bytes the shell says "too big").

If you want to find some examples of big scripts, look at the `configure` scripts for just about any self-configuring open source product.  The Perl 5.14.1 `Configure` script is 23.6K lines and 528 KiB.
The top-level `configure` script for GCC 4.6.2 is a mere 15.5K lines and 456 KiB; the configure script for its standard C++ library is 68.8K lines and 1806 KiB.  These are generated scripts rather than hand-crafted scripts, but the shell still has to handle them.